# Error on showing .js as spatial object with JSON.parse()

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, json

I have a Leaflet map exported by qgis2web plugin.
 The geodata is stored as (Geo-)JSON-objects inside a variable saved as .js-file.
I have an attribute field ("bildpfad") with comma-separated pathes to images I want to show in popups. 
For showing the images, I need access to every single path. That works by converting the path-field to an array and going through every single element with `array.forEach()`. 
 
Actually I am using the `JSON.parse()` function. I have other workspaces where this way works great, but not in that specific one.

I got following error message in the browser console:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

I've already validated the JSON-object without any errors. For testing purposes I reduced the hole dataset to one feature, but with the same error-message. Here  the JSON-data I'm using:

```
var json_spielgeraete_freizeit_2 = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "spielgeraete_freizeit_2",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "name": "spielgeraete_freizeit_2",
        "crs": {
            "type": "name",
            "properties": {
                "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
            }
        },
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "bildpfad": "\"U:\\ER-GIS-Verbunddokumente-Baumgrün\\spielgeraete\\1010443.JPG\"",
            "kategorie": "Wippgerät"        
        },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPoint",
        "coordinates": [
            [10.9846280196624, 49.572284008148969]
        ]
    }
}]
}]
}
```

And here the corresponding JavaScript part:

```
var string = feature.properties['bildpfad'] !== nullAutolinker.link(String(feature.properties['bildpfad'])) : '';
var path_array = JSON.parse("["+string+"]");
var popupContent = 
        '<div class="datagrid">\
            <table>\
            <thead>\
            <th>test</th>\
            </thead>\
                <tbody>\
                <tr>\
                <td>test</td>\
                </tr>\''                
                path_array.forEach(path_array => popupContent += '<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><img src="'+path_array+'" width="250px" </td></tr>')
                popupContent += '</tbody></table></div>';


        layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {maxHeight: 400});
    }
```

I don't think the umlauts ä,ö,ü causing the problem, removing them doesn't make any difference. The same by adding/removing / or \ in front of unsupported characters like /. I'm new in JavaScript, so maybe I'm misunderstanding some syntax rules in JSON-files (e.g. keywords or quotations marks) or somewhere else.

Comment: This might allready have an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524933/json-parse-unexpected-character-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has turned out that I don't even need to use the `JSON.parse()` function. 
`feature.properties['bildpfad']` hands a string and I just have to split it into single parts. All in all I don't have to handle with JSON structures, except of the strored geodata.
   `string.split(',')` splits the hole comma sperated string and stores it into an array. I simply have to access these array by  `array.forEach` and the hole thing works. As simple as it sounds. 
In this context it would be important to mention when working with paths to images that absolute paths to drive-paths e.g. `C:\images\1.jpg` can't opened by html. You always have to put `file:\\` in front of the path.